# python can't send post request image

Tags: python, image, post, request

I'm trying to decode a qr image from a website with python: https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx
And i don't know why my post requests fail and i don't get any response

```
import requests
url ="https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx" 
session = requests.Session()
f = {'f':open("new.png","rb")} 
response = session.post(url,files = f)
f = open("page.html","w")
f.write(response.text)
f.close()
session.close()
```

Even when i do it with a get requests it still fail ... :/

```
url ="https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx" 
session = requests.Session()
data = {'u':'https://www.qrstuff.com/images/default_qrcode.png'}
response = session.post(url,data = data)
f = open("page.html","w")
f.write(response.text)
f.close()
session.close()
```

maby because the website contain two forms ? ... 
Thanks for helping

Comment: try intercepting the requests using tamper data in Firefox. evaluate the requests and change code accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i just saw my mistake  ...
the web site is : https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx
but once you have a post or a get it'll be 
https://zxing.org/w/decode without ".jspx" so i just removed it and every thing worked well !!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
import urllib

url ="https://zxing.org/w/decode?u=https://www.qrstuff.com/images/default_qrcode.png" 
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
f = open("page.html","w")
f.write(response.read())
f.close()
```

If you want to send url `action == get` and if you want to post data as a file, `action == post`.
You can check it with `Hackbar` addons on `Firefox`